# Regex Expression seperating integer and real numbers

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex expression about matching integers and real numbers  (they are separated by dot, ex: 123.123) in a string where they are seperated by commas ","

I wrote this, but cannot separate them with comma: `^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+?$`

234                  match
345,2.78             match
5.443,214.0              match
4.5,12,0.8               match
1,1.0,3,4.8,0.0,0,7.001,8.0      match

2, 5                no match
3 4,5               no match
4.0,                no match
6F              no match
04              no match
5.00                no match
4-1             no match
11,,4.5             no match
4.              no match
.9              no match
1.22.34             no match

Comment: Can you provide an example of this string?

Comment: What language are you using ? You could just use a split() function with ',' as a delimiter, if all you want to do is retrieve all the values separated by a comma in a string.

Comment: I am using in int linux with pcregrep and split is not acceptable in my situation

Comment: 234      match   
345,2.78    match    
5.443,214.0      match      
4.5,12,0.8       match         
1,1.0,3,4.8,0.0,0,7.001,8.0      match 


2, 5     no match    
3 4,5    no match  
4.0,    no match  
6F    no match  
04    no match  
5.00    no match  
4-1    no match  
11,,4.5    no match  
4.    no match  
.9    no match  
1.22.34    no match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:\.\d+(?<!0)|\.0)?(?:\,(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:\.\d+(?<!0)|\.0)?)*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o4yf2K/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much. One final thing pcregrep does not accepting !0 this definition. can i replace it with !\0?

Comment: 0 and \0 means the same thing so yes but ! is part of the negative lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=,|^)[-+]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*(?=,|$)
```

should work.

`^` and `$` in your regex means: Beginning and End of the String. So you will get a match only if your string contains only one number.

`(?<=,|^)` and `(?=,|$)` are a positiv lookbehind and a positiv lookahead and means: only exact matches between commas or at the beginning or at the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you for response. But it should avoid matching of ex, 3.3.3 in this example it is not checking this.

Comment: I made an edit to the answer, so that 3.3.3 now should be skiped. What about : 3.,-.3 and -.?

Comment: Thanks Leonhard. Everything is good. For example, it matches 234,234,32.324.23...324 but actually it should not match. 123.123123,123,0.444,3434.3434 it should match this